# 'Correct' term for.. upwards moving menu?

Tags: menu, terminology

Dropdown menu.

But ours open upward - 'popup', as in 'popup menu' has proved oddly confusing to some of our business oriented folk. So we tried throwing in 'vertical menu' and then.. this was a mistake.. 'vertical animating menu'.. so what would you call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a "rise-up" or "spring-up" menu? If there's an animation attached to it, maybe a slide-up or a fade-in menu.

I understand the confusion about "popup" since many people think of popups as new browser windows that appear when you click a link.

Comment: Yeah, ok, I think rise-up will cut it, not much confusion there - it doesn't 'roll off the tongue', but it's more important that there's no confusion I think :)

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a linguistic anomaly. Maybe the folks at http://english.stackexchange.com could be of service as well?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/fwd-correct-term-for-upwards-moving-menu

Comment: Alrighty: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/fwd-correct-term-for-upwards-moving-menu, suggests "Rising Menu", which I quite like!

Answer (score 0):

"[Context menus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_menu)" are context-sensitive menus that appear at the site of a user interaction, such as a right-mouse click.

"Pull-down" menus are those that appear in menu bars.